# Why is energy usually concentrated on low frequency modes in dynamics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, vibrations, dissipation, coupled-oscillators

In all structural dynamics applications I have seen, the motion is mostly governed by low frequency modes. For example, a pretty accurate approximation of buildings dynamics can be obtained with the two or three lower frequency modes, provided the motion is linear.

That might be a silly question, but why is it so? The answer might be in the concept of modal mass but the physical interpretation of this observation is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two factors in play:

1. Ease of excitation. If you have wind driving a tall building, there is a force along the entire length of the building. This is most likely to excite the lowest frequency mode - in order to drive a higher mode, the driving force must be out of phase between different parts along the height of the building in just the right way.
2. Damping. Typically, higher frequencies will experience greater damping per unit time (same damping factor would result in same decrease in amplitude after a number of cycles - but that number of cycles is reached more quickly for the higher frequencies)

Comment: Your point 2 can be understood as solids acting like low-pass filters... which is certainly true.

Comment: 3. Higher frequency modes are higher energy for the same amplitude. If you cover the same distance in a smaller period, you have to move faster and that means more kinetic energy. Turned around, given equal energy in two modes, the higher frequency will have lower amplitude. And as Floris says, higher frequency modes typically lose energy faster.

Comment: @mmesser314 I don't disagree but the question was about "energy concentrated" not "largest amplitude" so I am not sure it is worth making a separate point out of it.

Comment: @Floris - True. I was looking at "motion is mostly governed by low frequency modes."